# I can't update sdk manager ' packages

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

I installed Xamarin on Visual studio 2013. I Unfortunately get the error: " The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required. Please update to the latest version." I updated to latest version but still it isn't the version that is needed for Xamarin!!! The SDK tools is v25.2.4, the Platform-tools is v25.0.2, the build-tools is v25.0.2.

I open sdk manager to update these packages but the link doesn't work!!

Is there any other way to resolve this sticky error??

Comment: Hi, I think you can solve the problem using a VPN.

Comment: @R.Mazarei Thank you very much for your reply. I use Psiphon3 but I don't get any result!

Comment: Try something else: HSS (HotspotShield). I had this problem too and I think it's related to the region.

Comment: @R.Mazarei Thank you. Ok. I'm going to test HSS, as well and will report the result.

Comment: @R.Mazarei HSS is too much slow. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can buy a VPN and use it but the HSS worked for me.

Comment: @R.Mazarei Thank you very much for your guides.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Make sure JDK 1.8 is installed--it is [required for API 24+](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/). Also check the paths are correct under Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings. What is the Visual Studio [version info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/)?

Comment: @ashley Thank you very much for your answer. It's been solved. I have another problem. Would you please have look at this  (forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/250272) link or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975532/the-installed-android-sdk-is-too-old-version-25-1-3-or-newer-is-required/41993139?noredirect=1) link?

Comment: It would be great to post your solution as an answer for this problem so other SO users will benefit.

Comment: @ashley Yes. Thank you very much for remembering me. I'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has filtered some countries to access these important installations and updates. Using a VPN is the solution.

Good luck.