# The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required."

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I installed Xamarin on Visual studio 2013. I Unfortunately get the error: " The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required. Please update to the latest version." I updated to latest version but I still get the same error!!!
These pictures show my SDK manager installations.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYZpi.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qc73.png)

And also I installed x86 jdk on my x64 based processor system type as recommended.

Well, how to get ride of this sticky error :( ! It made me crazy for a long time...

What should be installed? what should not be installed?!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the path from your SDK Manager matches the one configured for Xamarin in Visual Studio?

Comment: @tequilaslammer yes. It maches.

Answer (score 0):

> And also I installed x86 jdk on my x64 based processor system type as recommended.

I'm not sure which JDK have you installed, but Android Version 25.1.3 or newer requires [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). After installed this JDK, you need to open your VS and change the JDK path to this jdk 1.8 installed location:

Open **Tools** -> **Options**, then find the **Xamarin** table and choose **Android Settings**, then change the **Java Development Kit Location** to your installed location for example like this:

[image]

I'm using VS 2015, not 2013, but it should be similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but yes, the JDK  I've installed is also 1.8.0_121.

Comment: @AtefehMohammadpoor, the point is that have you change the path in your VS for JDK? Please read my entire answer.

Comment: This i my JDK path. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121. Could you please have a look at this [link] (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/250272). I explained there in more details. Thank you